# maximum response of image

Tags: image-processing, max, pixel

I am very much new to matlab.i am working on retinal image analysis .I want to find the maximum response of an image.I have 12 images .Now i have to compare all these images and find the maximum  pixel at each point and write it to a new image so that my new image is formed by maximum pixels.I am using matlab for this

```
            eg if my pixel value in 1 image is

    [9 8 6 3 2]
    and my 2 image is 
    [5 6 7 9 0].
   Now my 3rd new image should be

    [9 8 7 9 2]          %here i compare these two images on pixel by pixel conversion 
                          ie i compare 9 with 5 and write maximum value 9 to my new                    
                           image .next with 8 and 6 i take 8 since it is maximum.
```

this is just my own idea..Can this be done..How do i do it ny idea. I  have to comapre         10 images all together and create 11 image
   so far i have tried this

```
          A = getimage();
          I=A(:,:,2);
          lambda  = 8;
          theta   = 0;
          psi     = [0,pi/2];
          gamma   = 0.5;
          bw      = 1;
          N       = 12;
          angle = 0;
             theMaxValues = zeros(1, N);
        img_in = I;
       img_out = zeros(size(img_in,1), size(img_in,2), N);
        for n=1:N
         gb = gabor_fn(bw,gamma,psi(1),lambda,theta);

          %theMaxValues(n) = max(gb(:));
        I TRIED THIS WAY
        matrix(:,:,1) = gb;
       it gives me error..

 theta = angle+pi/180;
 angle= angle + 15;

      end
        [overallMax, index] = max(theMaxValues);
         thetaOfMax = theta(index);
         final_gb = gabor_fn(bw,gamma,psi(1),lambda,thetaOfMax); 
          figure;
         imshow(final_gb);
        title('final image');
```

Comment: You might want to add the programming language and toolkits you want to use.

Comment: sir i am using matlab .i tried using max function it gives me max value of entire image .I want the each and every pixel value.ny idea sir

Comment: possible duplicate of [comparing 12 filtered images to get the maximum response image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890379/comparing-12-filtered-images-to-get-the-maximum-response-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all your images into one Matrix, where the third dimension reprents the number ouf your image.

```
 matrix[:,:,1] %first image
 matrix[:,:,2] %second image and so on
```

Then you can simply search the maximum value at each Pixel along the third axis using

```
C = max(matrix,[],3)
```

Comment: sir ..sorry i did not get it sir!!!..m really sorry for my poor understanding. can u please explain me ..

Comment: What exactly is your Problem with my Answer? I can only help you if you describe your problem as good as possible.

Comment: sir i did it this way , i took 2 matrix just for testing...and did it this way and it gave me error :-( 

A =[1     2     3;1     2     3;4     5     3]
matrix(:,:,1)
ans = 0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0

>> B

B =

     2     3     4
     5     4     3
     1     2     3

>> matrix(:,:,2)
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: Please don´t add code to comments. Edit your Question to show what you are working on.

Comment: sir..i have edited it ..but i am very much new to matlab.i might have done some basic mistake..donno whr i am goin wrong

Comment: sir i got ua code and executed it .but i am getting this error donno how to solve this??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> file1>GABOR_Callback at 768
     img_out(:,:,1)= gb;